# ASP.Net MVC : Handle session for application using windows authetication

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed an application in ASP.NET MVC which works on windows authentication. I am using session, temp data kind of techniques to persist data in different requests.
But the problem here is that when the user keeps the system idle for more than 20 minutes variables in session, temp data are no longer available since the session is timeout.

To solve this problem I am planning to use below code.
I will make an ajax request every 20 minutes to keep the session.
So even if the user is idle, the system will not timeout and the user can start where he has left previously.

```
 setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                datatype: 'json',
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                       // alert("2 min");
                }
            });

        }, 1200000);
```

I want to know if their are any cons/disadvantages of using this approach.
Or any alternative approach to use in this case?

Comment: You can also increase the session timeout

Comment: If user lock system for the much more time say 6-7 hours or for entire day and access it again, is it good option to have session timeout that much longer for the applications say 7 hours or more than that?

Answer (score 0):

According to msdn

> The Timeout property cannot be set to a value greater than 525,600
>   minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes.

Increase in session time out will prevent the Server from releasing memory allocated to inactive session.

**Disadvantage:** You will have performance issues if you have large number of users and with increase in session timeout, your inactive sessions will remain in Web server memory which may cause application pool to recycle, which would result in loosing all sessions for all users.

Answer (score 0):

The value will depend on your application criticity but your webapp should always have a disconnection timout, because ... most user won't disconnect properly ...

If the page you call do nothing, your server won't suffer any problem for a moderate quantity of users (bellow 1000 simultaneous connection).

Your ajax call can be an option but a more clean scenario will be to just increase the session timeout value. I wouldn't recommand it to go over 2 hours, even on non-critical apps. in your web.config :

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="120"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go in different way. I would store your session temp data in SQL\other storage and map it to ASP.Net SessionID. When user signs in on the site, i would store his temp data on SQL based on SessionID. Also i would subscribe to Session_End event(that works only in InProc mode) and when session is timed out (20 minutes) i'll update data in DB based on session.

And then after a couple of hours of timeout, when user comes back in the same browser session - his SessionID will be the same and then if session is empty i would restore data from DB to that new session, so user won't see any difference. If he closes browser and starts it again, then session id will be new anyway and it will work the same as in your current approach.

Also i would have some task that will cleanup old sessions data in DB to don't garbage DB.

So in this approach your web server won't store useless sessions data for hours in AppPool process memory, and also it won't get tons of your keep alive requests like in your original question.

UPDATE: Other point is that by default IIS recycles AppPool each 24 hours or after 20 minutes of inactivity, so in your approach with keep alive - session will die anyway 24 hours later of web app launch and keep alive requests won't save it. In my approach it doesn't matter as we store temp session data in DB storage and it will be reloaded fine.